# How to Git fetch a remote repository and anchor it to a specified commit?

Tags: git

### The fictionalized story

Once upon a time two developers, Alice and Bob received a code base by e-mail. They have to work independently on the project, so they both used Git to track their modifications locally.

After some time, they both have multiple branches and hundred of commits.

Bob wants to get all Alice's work, so he does:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git remote add alice //john/project_foo/
$ git fetch alice master
```

He will get a new nice remote branch:

```
$ git branch -a
master
foo
bar
alice/master
```

Unfortunately `alice/master` branch is not connected with any of Bob's branch, though it is not possible to merge alice and bob work properly while keeping both history on the same repository...

### Issue details

Actually we've started from two independent repositories:

Alice's

```
*--A1--A2--A3--A4 (master)
```

Bob's

```
*--B1--B2--B3--A4 (master)
```

When Bob `fetch` Alice's work he got something that is parallel to his work:

```
*--A1--A2--A3--A4 (alice/master)
*--B1--B2--B3--A4 (master)
```

With this configuration it is not possible to do a 3-ways merge because there is no common ancestor between `alice/master` and `master`:

```
$ git checkout -b alice_on_bob master
$ git merge alice/master
```

What I rather would like to have is this:

```
*--B0--B1--B2 (master)
    \
     A0--A1--A2 (alice/master, alice_on_bob)
```

I suppose I can do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$ git checkout -b alice_merge B1
$ git fetch alice master:alice_merge
From //alice/foo
! [rejected]      master -> alice_merge (non-fast-forward)
```

### Concrete example of Alice and Bob

We consider this `Makefile` that will init the example (in case you wanna try at home):

```
# Makefile
files = $(shell echo {0..9}.txt)

init: fill_alice fill_bob

alice: origin
    cp -R $< $@
    cd $@; git init; git add .; git commit -m "$@ 0"; \
    git tag -a $@_0 -m "$@ 0"

bob: origin
    cp -R $< $@
    cd $@; git init; git add .; git commit -m "$@ 0"; \
    git tag -a $@_0 -m "$@ 0"

origin: 
    mkdir $@; \
    cd $@; \
    for i in $(files); \
    do \
      tr -dc a-z1-4 </dev/urandom | \
      tr 1-2 ' \n' | \
      awk 'length==0 || length>50' | \
      tr 3-4 ' ' | \
      sed 's/^ *//' | \
      cat -s | \
      sed 's/ / /g' | \
      head -n10 > $$i; \
    done; \

fill_alice: alice
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 10  >> $</2.txt
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 10  >> $</3.txt
    cd $<; git commit -m "$< 1" .
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 10  >> $</2.txt
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 10  >> $</3.txt
    cd $<; git commit -m "$< 2" .

fill_bob: bob
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 10  >> $</2.txt
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 10  >> $</3.txt
    cd $<; git commit -m "$< 1" .
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 10  >> $</2.txt
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 10  >> $</3.txt
    cd $<; git commit -m "$< 2" .

fetch:
    cd bob && git remote add alice ../alice/
    cd bob && git checkout bob_0
    cd bob && git fetch alice master:alice_on_bob
    cd bob && git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate

clean:
    rm -rf alice
    rm -rf bob
    rm -rf origin
```

It will produce this file hierarchy:

```
|
|- alice/
|  |- .git/
|  |- 0.txt/
|  |- .../
|  +- 9.txt/
|
+- bob/
   |- .git/
   |- 0.txt/
   |- .../
   +- 9.txt/
```

Where we have 3 commits on both Alice and Bob:

```
$ cd alice && git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate
* 5041abd (HEAD, master) alice 2
* 0d4090c alice 1
* 4c2c393 (tag: alice_0) alice 0

$ cd bob && git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate
* b0846cb (HEAD, master) bob 2
* 594407f bob 1
* 86b3b46 (tag: bob_0) bob 0
```

Now we add the remote from Bob to Alice and we try to do something that we will not work because I don't know how to do it...

```
$ git remote add alice ../alice/
$ git checkout bob_0
$ git fetch alice master:bob_0  # Will not work
$ git checkout master
$ git merge alice_on_bob
```

The goal is to get this:

```
$ cd bob && git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate
* 458ae6d (HEAD, master)
|\    
* | b0846cb bob 2
* | 594407f bob 1
| * 5041abd (alice_on_bob) alice 2
| * 0d4090c alice 1
| * 4c2c393 (tag: alice_0) alice 0
|/
* 86b3b46 (tag: bob_0) bob 0
```

But I only got this:

```
$ cd bob && git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate
* 558e0a9 (alice/master, alice_on_bob) alice 2
* 74a1bdd alice 1
* 014273d (tag: alice_0) alice 0
* 9bb89b2 (master) bob 2
* c245cd2 bob 1
* 3ff5abc (HEAD, tag: bob_0) bob 0
```

### Summarized question

> I would like to import a remote branch from another Git repository into a new branch starting from a selected commit. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the non-existence of a shared remote, you could try the approach of applying a patch Alice should send you. So what Alice could do is the following:

`$ git format-patch master --stdout > alices.patch`

She sends you here patch and you apply the patch by doing the following:

`$ git checkout -b integration` --> This is to keep your master safe and clean for testing

`$ git am < alices.patch
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --no-ff integration
$ git branch -D integration`

But I would suggest to set up a shared remote where Alice and Bob could share there work easily with different branches ;)

## Updated Answer for the updated Question:

What you could try is `git cherry-pick` all the commits from `alice/master` to your `alice_on_bob_master` and merge them afterwards to your master.

What you definitely can not achieve is your actual main goal of having the commits from `alice/master` starting at a particular commit of your master.

Comment: This is a good advise, unfortunately in my specific example we did not work with a common bare repository and Alice is not there but her PC is on. So I can do `git pull` but I cannot go on her PC and prepare the patch. Moreover, with a patch I will lose all her commits. If I want to explore her change commit after commit, I will need to fetch all her commits not just the full diff.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run git branch I will only see my own branches not alice/master

adding the flag(s) `git branch -a` will display all the branches

> However, when I try to branch on it with git checkout alice/master I get a detached head
>   This is how git behave, if you wish to work on this branch you will need to create new branch with the `git checkout -b <branch_name>`.

The command `git checkout remote/branch' is equivalent to`git checkout `the 'remotes/branch' simply grab the value of the`SHA-1`from the ref file and checking out that commit. Look on`remote/branch` as an human-redable SHA-1

> So I am a bit lost because I realize that alice/master is not really a branch.

As explained above its an "alias" to certain commit (The latest commit in the given branch)

> How can I properly diff and merge Alice's work into my repository and in the case of a three-way-merge what will be the common ancestor?

try this out:

```
git checkout my_branch
git pull origin/master
// This should result in a fast-forward merge (No extra merge commit)
```

`git pull` is an alias for 2 git commands: `git fetch && git merge`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have a misquoting in your answer (I cannot edit it because I have to change more than 6 chars...)